How to edit value from a linked table in a dropdown(<select>) box?
How to output and edit columns of a many-to-many table through <select\>.
I have three tables : filial_work , department_work, contact_work .
In them, I managed to output only the already assigned id_filial(id_department) , but I need everything to be output and they can be changed.
filial_work :
id_filial | filial

department_work :
id_department | department | department_email

contact_work:
id_contact | id_filial | id_department | full_name | email_user | work_number | tel_number

script for outputting a string by ip from the contact_work table
<?php
include "../src/php/connect_db_tel-sprav-contact.php";
$id_contact = $_GET['id'];
$result = mysqli_query($induction, "SELECT * FROM `contact_work` WHERE `id_contact` = '$id_contact'");
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/src/css/Create_contact_style.css">
  <title>Editing a contact</title></head>
<body>
<header><img src="/src/img/01-logo.webp" alt="Centrospas-Yugoria logo">
  <h1 class="logo">Editing a contact</h1></header>
<nav></nav>
<main></main>
<div class="visual_create_new_user">
  <form action="/src/php/script_change_contact.php " method="post"> //script for outputting a string by ip from the
    contact_work table<input type="hidden" name="id_contact" value="<?= $result['id_contact'] ?>">
    <p>
      <button onclick="location.href='/src/TEST_Admin_Contact.php'">Back to contacts</button>
    </p>
    <p>Change Branch: <select>
        <option><?= $result['id_filial'] ?></option>
      </select></p>
    <p>Change Department: <select>
        <option><?= $result['id_department'] ?></option>
      </select></p>
    <p>Change the Position: <input type="text" name="_post" value="<?= $result['post'] ?>"></p>
    <p>Change your FULL NAME: <input required type="text" name="full_name" value="<?= $result['full_name'] ?>"></p>
    <p>Change Email: <input type="text" name="email_user" value="<?= $result['email_user'] ?>"></p>
    <p>Change the work phone number: <input type="text" name="work_number" value="<?= $result['work_number'] ?>"></p>
    <p>Change personal phone number: <input type="text" name="tel_number" value="<?= $result['tel_number'] ?>"></p>
    <p>
      <button type="submit">Change</button>
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>


Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!

Do you have any specific question about all this code?

In order to populate a dropdown box with values from a linked table, you need to select them from this table.
Hence your code could be like this
// get your record
$id_contact = $_GET['id'] ?? 0;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `contact_work` WHERE `id_contact` = ?";
$contact = $db->execute_query($sql, [$id_contact])->fetch_assoc();

// get values from a linked table
$sql = "SELECT id, department FROM `department_work`";
$departments = $db->query($sql)->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

And then you can create your dropdown like this.
<p>Change Department:
  <select name = "id_department">
  <?php foreach ($departments as $dep): ?>
    <?php $selected = ($dep['id'] === $contact['id_department']) ? "selected" : "" ?>
    <option value="<?= htmlspecialchars($dep['id']) ?" <?= $selected ?>>
      <?= htmlspecialchars($dep['department']) ?>
    </option>
  <?php endforeach ?>
  </select>
</p>

Note the changes I made

added a name for dropdown input
added a loop that displays options
added a condition that sets the current value as selected
prepared statements MUST be used for database interaction
htmlspecialchars() MUST be used to escape all values printed inside HTML


Hi ! Do you use PDO? I'm just writing using mysqli, can this cause problems when using your method to solve my problems?

Check the link provided in the answer. Or here it is in Russian
